Existence of a Restricted Set of Orthogonal Functions
Let $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_0^1 f(\theta)d\theta=0$ and $f \neq 0$ ($f$ is not almost everywhere zero). Does there exist a set of function $\mathcal{G}$ such that

$\forall g \in \mathcal{G}, g \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, and $\int_0^1 f(\theta)g(\theta) d\theta=0$
card($\mathcal{G})$ $>$ card($[0,1]$)
for all finite subset of $\mathcal{G}$, denote a generic one as $G=\{g_1,...,g_n\}$, $g_1,...,g_n$ are linearly independent

The third condition might appear to be unorthodox, but it is inspired by the condition where a homogeneous system of linear equations has the unique $x=0$ solution.
Any hints, examples, or references would be greatly appreciated!
